# Syntax Error with Query

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2

I would like to use an `Insert Into` query in Delphi XE2 to insert a user's information into a MS Access Database. The problem is I keep getting the same error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

I have done some research but there is no definitive answer. my source code is:

```
  opendb('QuizDB.mdb');

  DB.Close;
  DB.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblUsers');
  DB.SQL.Add('(FirstName,Surname,Username,Password,Grade)');
  DB.SQL.Add('Values (:Firstname, :Surname, :Username, :Password, :Grade)');

  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Firstname').Value := pFirstname;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Surname').Value := pSurname;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Username').Value := pUsername;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Password').Value := pPassword;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Grade').Value := pGrade;
  DB.ExecSQL;
```

QuizDB being the database name, DB being a ADOQuery component and then p(var) being variables received as parameters.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

`PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access so if you use it as a column name you must enclose it in square brackets.

Try this instead:

```
DB.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblUsers ');
DB.SQL.Add('(FirstName,Surname,Username,[Password],Grade) ');
```

Comment: Thanks so much. IT worked all I needed to do was add those brackets.

Comment: There must be close to a hundred questions regarding this trap.